# Typescript extract keys from an object where each key value has a specific property

Tags: typescript

I have a read-only object that is used to represent the stats for my game like so:

```
const STATS = {
  gp: {
    name: "Games Played",
    slug: "GP",
  },
  minp: {
    name: "Minutes Played",
    slug: "MINP",
  },
  minpg: {
    name: "Average Minutes Per Game",
    slug: "MINPG",
    generated: {
      // ...properties,
    },
  },
  avgrec: {
    name: "Average Receptions",
    slug: "avgrec",
    generated: {
      // ...properties,
    },
  },
} as const;
```

I want to extract all the keys from the object that have a **generated** property set. That way I can use this key in some of my utility functions. Thus, I tried the below:

```
type GeneratedStatKeys = {
  [I in keyof typeof STATS]: typeof STATS[I]["generated"] extends undefined
    ? never
    : typeof STATS[I];
}; // "minpg" | "avgrec"
```

GeneratedStatKeys should be a union type of strings, the extracted keys of STATS. However, Typescript is throwing an error "Type '"generated"' cannot be used to index type STATS"

This makes sense, so I annotated the STATS object to be:

```
const STATS: Record<string, Stat> = {
//...stats
} as const;
```

where Stat is:

```
interface Stat {
  name: string;
  slug: string;
  generated?: {
  //...props
  };
}
```

This works, however, GeneratedStatKeys type is then string.

What is the workaround? I could just manually create a string union type for the generated keys but was wondering if this could be "automated".

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wE7zgm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a type with a key unless it's a known key of the type.  Since some of the properties of `typeof STATS` don't have a `generated` key, you can't index into an arbitrary property that way.  Instead you could *check* if the property has that key by using [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator):

```
type GeneratedStatKeys = {
  [K in keyof typeof STATS]: "generated" extends keyof typeof STATS[K] ? K : never
}[keyof typeof STATS]
// type GeneratedStatKeys = "avgrec" | "minpg"
```

Once you did this check you could do the indexed access (e.g., `"generated" extends keyof Foo ? Foo[K] : ...`) but in your case you just want the key, not the property type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBAygFQIILjAvDA3gWAFAwwDmADgFzb6GFgCGAtgKYUBEA4g4xDAAoA2tAJ6MAJiwA0VahD4BXIqzY8JUgL6SCMegEsw5SppqdWAWV2yoXXgOFiN1GDPmmAkgDll9mOqk69Cgwc6JlYkADdGACdaIkYYMzALKx4omA4mFUNHOQCWE3ceNkyHWLAo2ksRClwswgB6OpgAOhaSSJASKKhtLi9CH00BwlowokjGYGqpIxCYFnDy2JgAJQnGEm7wCGLpHNYRsYmdwlLyyqnamAbm1vbOyO7e6e8vAdUYWm5QSCgAbnwAXgoIJOmlGGVopU4FAKgBpRiCbiYGqEADasJguhgAGsESAAGYwYGdAnwZCoAC6rFOkNELBgjAAHpYwCJuLjBKTiYxSYgUHB0RSYAB+GAYihlCKRfCqVEcrkgnmEvmU-DXblgiEVUTQuEIpFzA7jYD0gA+cz8JCILCAA)